# DTLS Handshake Failure In Android Device

Tags: android, openssl, webrtc, handshake, dtls

I am trying to implement DTLS in my Android client using `openssl/bio.h` library.

The same does not cause any errors in iOS, while in Android..the DTLS handshake failure gives the following error
`ssl3_write_pending:BIO_NOT_SET`

I do not understand that error, has anyone tried this before or faced this issue? Did not find much help through google

Comment: WebRTC comes with it's own DTLS module, why use another?

Comment: @Kevin I am not using the complete Webrtc code .I am just using the Audio Module of Webrtc and that is why I am implementing DTLS on my own

Comment: Then your question shouldn't be flagged as webrtc....

Comment: I guess that some more context, especially code, could help solve this issue (faster).

Answer (score 0):

I got the DTLS Handshake working after changing my DTLS code ,which was earlier using OpenSSL TO BoringSSL.I changed all the functions signature from that of OpenSSL to BoringSSL.

Comment: Are you facing any issue?

Comment: I'm trying to use SpongyCastle's DTLS implementation but because of the lack of update frequency regarding BouncyCastle, I'm looking to other libraries that can offer the DTLS implementation. Last option would be to do my own implementation, that I would like as much as possible to avoid for security reasons. Scandium seems also to have a good DTLS java implementation.